# Find out deleted text of QPlainTextEdit

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qt5.1

```
void QTextDocument::contentsChange(int position, int charsRemoved, int charsAdded) [signal]
```

This signal is emitted whenever the document's content changes; for example, when text is inserted or deleted, or when formatting is applied.

User can click cut/press delete/backspace or any other way and will remove text. 
Problem is this signal emitted after text is removed. So I don't know which text was deleted.Now position and charsRemoved are of no use.

I want to find out deleted text of QPlainTextEdit. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see 2 possible solutions:

1. Store the contents of the document after every contents change, so in every next change you will have access to the previous contents and you will be able to extract the value using *position* and *charsRemoved*.

   **Pros:** It's isolated mechanism and will not interfere with any other signals or slots.

   **Cons:** It implies significant memory and CPU footprint (every text change causes full string copy).
2. (a better one in my opinion) In the slot function implementation use the `undo()` and `redo()` methods of the `QPlainTextEdit` to restore previous contents for the time of querying *charsRemoved*. Note, that calling `undo()` and `redo()` **will not** trigger the `contentsChange()` signal (I just tested it), so it's as simple as that.

   **Pros:** Doesn't cause additional memory footprint. Not sure about the CPU footprint, but I think it's also better in that case.

   **Cons:** This will only work with *Undo/Redo* mechanism enabled (which it is by default) and it also might affect any undo/redo code that you use or override (usually it's not the case).

To be clear, a sample code snipped for solution 2:

```
void MainWindow::textChanged(int pos, int rem, int add)
{
    ui->plainTextEdit->undo();
    qDebug() << ui->plainTextEdit->document()->toPlainText().mid(pos, rem); // <- text removed
    ui->plainTextEdit->redo();
    qDebug() << ui->plainTextEdit->document()->toPlainText().mid(pos, add); // <- text added
}
```

Comment: Thanks its nice solution

I was already using method 1 but not much happy to keep two sources. 

Let me try second one. looks good.

Comment: Hi googie I just noticed you are creator of sqlite studio. I'm big fan.

I've created kineticwing.com and working on its next advanced version.

Comment: Calling undo and redo for big text making app crash.
Its crashing somewhere in event stack which I can't see. If I remove undo and redo its starts working normal.

I've to use method 1 which is more stable but memory consuming.

Answer (score 2):

The trick with calling `undo` and `redo` suggested by Googie is nice, to make it even more efficient one can use a `QTextCursor` to extract the text instead of calling `toPlainText`:

```
void TextEdit::slotCheckRange(int pos, int removed, int added){
    if(removed > 0){
        undo();
        QTextCursor c(textCursor());
        c.setPosition(pos);
        c.setPosition(pos + removed, QTextCursor::KeepAnchor);
        qDebug() << "Removed: " << removed << " (" << c.selectedText() << ")";
        redo();
    }
    if(added > 0){
        QTextCursor c(textCursor());
        c.setPosition(pos);
        c.setPosition(pos + added, QTextCursor::KeepAnchor);
        qDebug() << "Added: " << added << " (" << c.selectedText() << ")";
    }
}
```